# My xamarin app freezes when i try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <T>

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, json.net

When I get a json response from HttpClient () and try to deselize, my Xamarin application freezes (UI works, but the code after in class ExecuteGetRequest line 15 does not work). What can it be because of?
No errors.

I call the method of obtaining a list of anime user

```
        ShikimoriMain shikimoriMain = new ShikimoriMain();
        var UserInformation = await shikimoriMain.GetUserInformation(Convert.ToInt64(UserID));
        var UserAnimeList = await shikimoriMain.GetUserAnimeList(Convert.ToInt64(UserID), 1, 5);
        string animeName = UserAnimeList.Anime[0].Anime.Name;
```

ShikimoriMain.GetUserAnimeList

```
    public async Task<ShikimoriUserAnimeList> GetUserAnimeList(long id, int page, int limit)
    {
        string[] args = new string[] { ShikimoriCategories.UserID + "/" + id + ShikimoriCategories.UserAnimeList + $"?limit={limit}&page={page}" };
        return await ExecuteGetRequest<ShikimoriUserAnimeList>(args);
    }
```

ExecuteGetRequest

```
    public async Task<T> ExecuteGetRequest<T>(string[] args) where T : class
    {
        T returnedObject;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{httpApiv1}/{args}");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, httpApiv1 + String.Join("/", args));
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Search Anime");
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request);
            string json = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // successfully get json

            returnedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json); // after that the code is not executed

            return returnedObject;
        }
    }
```

ShikimoriUserAnimeList

```
public class ShikimoriUserAnimeList
{
    [JsonProperty()]
    public List<GetAnime> Anime { get; set; }
}

public class GetAnime
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("anime")]
    public Anime Anime { get; set; }
}

public class Anime
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("russian")]
    public string NameRU { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("image")]
    public AnimeImage AnimeImage { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("kind")]
    public string King { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("score")]
    public string Score { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("episodes")]
    public int Episodes { get; set; }
}

public class AnimeImage
{
    [JsonProperty("original")]
    public string Original { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("preview")]
    public string Preview { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("x96")]
    public string ImageX96 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("x48")]
    public string ImageX48 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You sure it is not an Exception that is stopping the method from executing any further? Have you tried wrapping the `JsonConvert`with a `try catch block` just to be sure?

Comment: Thank, it's help me. But it’s strange that there were no errors in the device log

Comment: The exception should pop up in the output window when running the application. I don't know why it did not for you. So the issue is resolved?

Comment: If question is answered and issue is resolved, please add an answer with the solution and accept it. (You can accept your own answers). Doing this would keep potentially helpful people from looking at this question thinking it still needs an answer and save these helpful folks some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completion:

An error was being thrown but was not visible in the device log. Wrapping the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)` in a `try catch block` helped finding the `Exception`being thrown.

```
try 
{
    returnedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json); // after that the code is not executed

    return returnedObject;
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
 ... (debug and fix the error that occurred)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I've realized that using **HttpClient** **async** will cause **deadlock** in **winforms** or **xamarin** (however it **works well** with **Asp**) and I changed these lines

```
  HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request);
  string json = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // successfully get json
```

Like these (Make them work synchronous):

```
  HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
  string json = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; // successfully get json
```

And change your method as default **synchronous**

Take a look at [Here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2150543.aspx?HttpClient%20PostAsync%20caught%20in%20a%20deadlock)

Comment: Is that wise aint that the whole point of async